# How to make a whole 'div' clickable in html and css without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, click

I want to make it so that a whole div is clickable and links to another page when clicked without JavaScript and with valid code/markup.

If I have this which is what I want the result to do -

```
<a href="#">
<div>This is a link</div>
</a>
```

The W3C validator says that block elements shouldn't be placed inside an inline element. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: just [add a click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to the div?

Comment: Define valid code? With or without JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean "clickable"? Do you want an event to fire? Or do you have some event on that div that isn't being fired on every spot on the div you could click on? There needs to be more context.

Comment: does html and css include javascript? dont think so

Comment: I DO think so, buddy. It's pretty much a standard nowadays. Anyhow, a dom element is a dom element. nesting the div in an a tag shouldn't invalidate your site.

Comment: @KaiQing so by your reckoning, you can nest a head tag inside a body tag and that's OK? Semantic markup is there for a reason. If everything was governed by the fact that everything is a DOM element, we may as well just have one tag called object.

Comment: Just make the `<a>` a block element.

Comment: having a div inside inside <a> is valid from html5

Comment: *clickable* and *a link to something* is very different, I don't see how this is a duplicate. *Clickable* means it fires a click event.

Comment: By adding padding and equal amounts of negative margin you can 'expand' the area that is clickable on the <a> tag.  For example: if an <a> tag is in a list of <div> elements and each <a> is has an icon before it and a <span> after it. To cause the icon and the span at either side of the <a> element to be clickable i added this css:  padding-left: 25px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-right: -30px;

Comment: .clickableDivInsideDiv {
    position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> a whole div links to another page when clicked without javascript and
>   with valid code, is this possible?

Pedantic answer: No.

As you've already put on another comment, it's invalid to nest a `div` inside an `a` tag.

However, there's nothing preventing you from making your `a` tag behave very similarly to a `div`, with the exception that you cannot nest other block tags inside it. If it suits your markup, set `display:block` on your `a` tag and size / float it however you like.

If you renege on your question's premise that you need to avoid javascript, as others have pointed our you can use the onClick event handler. jQuery is a popular choice for making this easy and maintainable.

**Update:**

In HTML5, placing a `<div>` inside an `<a>` is valid.

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes (thanks [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665923/damien))

Comment: As of HTML5, having a `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag is valid: "the a element is now transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to also contain flow content". http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes

Comment: brilliant @Damien, you are correct. <a href="#">
<div></div>
</a> is valid HTML5. Thank you for simplifying my life!

Comment: Alex, it would be good if you updated the answer to reflect Damien's comment. It's really valuable info, and it's a shame that it's hidden in a comment...

Comment: Updated URL for document Damien is referencing: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#content-model, then text search "The a element now" to locate on page

Comment: Doesn't this solution create a potential problem for other <a> tags in the document? I may not want all my <a> tags redefined like this. As noted by @Damien the <div> inside an <a>  seems the most elegant.

Comment: Make sure that `<a>` tag doesn't contain another `<a>` tag in it. Otherwise, the `<div>` inside `<a>` won't be clickable.

Answer (score 175):

It is possible to make a link fill the entire div which gives the appearance of making the div clickable.

***CSS:***

```
#my-div {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
a.fill-div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my-div">
    <a href="#" class="fill-div"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: See this page to make it work properly in Internet Explorer (basically just set the width or height to 1%: http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/154/simple-css-how-to-make-clickable-areas-bigger

Comment: I believe the 1% hack is needed only for <= IE6, possibly IE7.  Anyone know for sure?

Comment: The `a` will not fill a `td` that has padding, and I assume the same is true for a `div`. I'm not sure if there's a way around it other than removing padding from the container. Negative margins on the `a` do not help. HTML4. `a` also shrinks to nothing if it is not surrounding anything.

Answer (score 138):

```
<div onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>
```

Comment: The OP specified "without javascript".

Comment: onclick uses javascript, so this is a solution to clickable divs, but not answer to the question, in which the OP asked for a method 'without javascript'

Comment: credits: https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/making-a-div-element-clickable-in-html/

Answer (score 24):

Without JS, I am doing it like this:

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sometext">Some text here</div>
  <div class="someothertext">Some other text here</div>
  <a href="#" class="mylink">text of my link</a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
}

.container.a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999px; //these two lines are to hide my actual link text.
  overflow: hidden; //these two lines are to hide my actual link text.
}
```

Comment: Won't only text part be clickable?

Comment: no, the whole container area will be clickable because <a> covers all the area inside container.

Answer (score 11):

My solution without JavaScript/images. Only CSS and HTML. It works in all browsers.

***HTML:***

```
<a class="add_to_cart" href="https://www.example.com" title="Add to Cart!">
  buy now<br />free shipping<br />no further costs
</a>
```

***CSS:***

```
.add_to_cart:hover {
  background-color:#FF9933;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.add_to_cart {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#EC5500;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:8px;
  width:90px;
  height:31px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#E70000;
}
```

Comment: You of course mean "only HTML and CSS".

Comment: Where's the `<div>`? This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: He added `display:block` to his `a` tag, making it behave like a `div`. It gets you the same result.

Answer (score 10):

Nesting block level elements in anchors is **not invalid** anymore in **HTML5**. See http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html.
I'm not saying you should use it, but in HTML5 it's fine to use `<a href="#"><div></div></a>`.

The accepted answer is otherwise the best one. Using JavaScript like others suggested is also bad because it would make the "link" **inaccessible** (to users without JavaScript, which includes search engines and others).

Comment: Brilliant, and standards-based.

Answer (score 4):

```
.clickable {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't add any "clickable" functionality. It only changes the cursor.

Comment: True. Worked for my purposes :))

Comment: The only way this would really work properly is to add some JavaScript, which is kind of pointless in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery would allow you to do that.

Look up the `click()` function:
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Example:

```
$('#yourDIV').click(function() {
  alert('You clicked the DIV.');
});
```

Comment: OP asked for no javascript

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe He edited his post after I submitted the answer.

Comment: @JoshFoskett I would, instead of showing an alert box, to redirect to another page (like a usual href). How can I do that? I come across something like localtion.href, does that help?

Comment: @DiAlex This should work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/mdc2h/

Comment: Thx! I ended using something very similar, also using the click event:  `$("#div-id").click(function() { location.href = "./page.html"; });`

Answer (score 2):

Well you could either add `<a></a>` tags and place the div inside it, adding an href if you want the div to act as a link. Or else just use Javascript and define an 'OnClick' function. But from the limited information provided, it's a bit hard to determine what the context of your problem is.

Comment: i already use this but it sais your not aloud to put block elements inside inline elements so was tryna find a good way to do it (:

Comment: OP asked for "valid code" (I assume they meant valid *markup*) - nesting a tags inside divs is not valid.

Comment: As has been stated on other answers above, divs inside a tags are now valid html5. http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<div onclick="alert('test');">

</div>
```

Comment: While I normally don't encourage inline handlers, in this specific situation it might actually be the best option

Comment: OP asked for no javascript

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you will need at least a little bit of JavaScript...

I would suggest to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

You can include this library in one line. And then you can access your div with

```
$('div').click(function(){
  // do stuff here
});
```

and respond to the click event.

Comment: OP specified "without javascript".

Answer (score 0):

we are using like this

```
     <label for="1">
<div class="options">
<input type="radio" name="mem" id="1" value="1" checked="checked"/>option one
    </div>
</label>
   <label for="2"> 
<div class="options">
 <input type="radio" name="mem" id="2" value="1" checked="checked"/>option two
</div></label>
```

using

```
  <label for="1">
```

tag and catching is with

```
id=1
```

hope this helps.