# Background link (on ALL the background!)

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a whole 'div' clickable in html and css without javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript)

I've set up a 100% width/height div to stay on the background of the website, like so:

```
.background {
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.4);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

I'd like to have a link that would cover the WHOLE div, but if I code something like this, I'll have the link to appear only on the last part of the div (remember that this div has to stay in the background, with some divs above it), after the other divs, that stay above it.

```
<a href='/home'>
     <div class='background'></div>
</a>
```

Are there any HTML/CSS solutions?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=LINK+DIV

Comment: Just use an A tag set to display BLOCK with the same position, width and height values rather than the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `<div>` tags inside `<a>` tags. However, you can make the `<a>` behave like a `<div>` by utilizing the CSS `display:block` property.

**CSS**

```
*, html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.background {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="background"></a>​
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BU7mQ/2/)