# Hover only working on link, not whole div

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I'm designing a web page and I used HTML5 to make an entire div tag a link. Prior to adding the link, the whole div would expand when I hovered over it. Suddenly, it's only working if I hover over the words, not the box I created. The HTML looks like this (minus the actual link):

```
<a href="link goes here" style="text-decoration: none;">
<div class="home-tab">
home
</div>
</a>
```

And the CSS to make it hover looks sort of like this:

```
.home-tab:hover {
width: 150px;
height: 45px;
margin-top: 30px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
font-family: arial;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
font-size: 13pt;
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

(Note: This is not all of the code in the stylesheet. I have some lovely color in there too.)

Is there something I'm missing in my CSS to make the whole thing work on the hover and not just the words? I'm not even sure what questions to ask to figure out what I've done here.

ETA: I have checked this across three different browsers. It has the same problem on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

ETA: CSS without the :hover attribute.

```
.home-tab{
width: 150px;
height: 35px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
font-family: arial;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
font-size: 13pt;
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

ETA: Okay, here's something very weird. It seems that any elements on the far right don't have this problem. Seriously, the forums tab and next button on the far right both have :hover elements and they work exactly as I want them to.

Comment: More specifically, most browsers won't let you place a block-level element (i.e. a DIV) inside an inline element (A)

Comment: While it may not be for HTML, HTML5 does do this.

Comment: @KimberlyLewis Might need to cite a source on that.  News to me

Comment: HTML5 a-tag http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html allows flow content http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow, You are absolutly right @kimberlyLewis

Comment: can you provide the default (none hover) styling for the div as well, preferably here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/BNm7A/

Comment: Consider swapping the order of elements: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HfUEW/)

Comment: @PeterVR, Done. You'll notice that the only thing that changes is the height and any related margins/padding.

Comment: @KimberlyLewis, did you update? Can you provide a link?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in FF at least http://jsfiddle.net/Rk3NC/

Comment: Hm, I may need to eat a bit of crow here. I think your interpretation of the documentation is correct. Checking with the [validator](http://validator.w3.org) now...

Comment: Validator agrees: `<a ...><div></div></a>` is valid. I may need to rethink my worldview.

Comment: @PeterVR I'm having some trouble getting the jsfiddle site to work. The library network keeps shutting me out of it, claiming hacking. I may have to wait until tonight when I can repair the internet at home.

Comment: just post the code in your question then, I'll paste it in the fiddle for you (and you shouldn't hack ;-) )

Comment: @PeterVR Done. Code is now in my question.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/BNm7A/1/ And there is no need to repeat all the properties, just the ones you want to change

Comment: @PeterVR, maybe that's the problem? That I've repeated elements? I'm going to give that a shot in the IDE. ETA: Nope, doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `<div>` entirely and set `<a>` to `display: block`.

You're not supposed to put block-level elements inside of an `<a>` anyway.

Comment: HTML5 lets you do this. I checked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript) Also [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bcPs/)

The only thing I can think of is that the div is not the size you think it is.  the size and width elements that you are setting in your css are only active when your mouse is on the div.  You need to set them in the normal non hover settings as well if you want the div to be that size.  Right now it is defaulting to just large enough to hold the text.  You can see this demonstrated by the black border I added in my example.

Here is my suggestion:

```
.home-tab {
/*All of the sizing code goes here to create box for div*/
}
.home-tab:hover {
/*anything you want changed on hover goes here*/
}
```

I hope I was understanding your question correctly.  If you need more clarification please let me know. Good luck!

Comment: It's defaulting to just bigger than the text?  In what browser?  In current FF it is 100% width as a default div is.

Comment: I misspoke, the height is only as tall as the text.  It is the full width but very short.  I am using google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

*I think you want to expand that div when you hover cursor on that div.*
i wrote a code below that will solve your hover problem.
***Here is a code for you customize this***

```css
.home-tab{
   width:150px;
   height:45px;
   margin-top:30px;
   color:#008080;
   font-family: arial;
   background-color: blue;
   transition-duration: .8s;
   color:white;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 13pt;
   padding-top: 25px;
}
.home-tab:hover{
    width:200px;
   height:60px;
   font-size: 16pt;
   
    transition-duration: .8s;
}
a{ text-decoration:none} /* optional*/
</style>
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="home-tab">
    home
</div>
  </a>
```