# Why this pop up is not shown?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, popup

I have a problem with a very simple JavaScript pop-up script.

I have this example page: http://www.onofri.org/example/example4/

At the end of this page there is a box containing some flags including the British flag that is reprsented by the **#reportEng** `div` (inside the **engLink link**).

What I want is that when the user clicks on this element a pop0up message will show.

So I have add to the page this simple script:

```
<script>
    var test = document.getElementById('engLink');
    test.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
</script>
```

I have put the script inside the **body section** of the page and not in the **head section** because this is only a test page and the final result will be put into a page of a CMS in which I do not have access to the template (so I can't put the script in the head section).

The problem is that it does not work. If I click on the English flag the page is reloaded and the pop-up not shown.

Can you help me?

Thank you,

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went a completely different approach.  The addEventListener is pretty cool, but I'm a bit OLD and I've defaulted to nasty habits.  This works just fine for me.

```
<script>
function myExample(){
    alert("BaZing!  It works!");
}
</script>
```

And for the HTML part...

```
<a href="" id="engLink"><div id="reportEng" onClick="myExample()"></div></a>
```

I also want to point out that this 'fix' is a bit taboo ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice))

Comment: I left your OLD JavaScript in there and added my own function.  But if this works for you I would remove your OLD code and just leave the new function (and you can remove my console.log(), that was just for fun).

Comment: Never mind, I just cleaned it up.  The OCD kicked in.  =/.  The newly edited code is all you need.

Comment: BTW, I downloaded your entire webpage and tested it in your code and it works (this is not 'dummy' code).

Answer (score 0):

You don't prevent the link from being followed, so when you click the link which has an empty `href`, you simply reload the current page.

There are many ways to prevent the defaul link behaviour, but here is the old school way:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="engLink"><div id="reportEng"></div></a>
```

Also on a side note I don't think a `div` element is allowed inside an `a` in HTML or XHTML.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SueKH/)

Comment: mmm I have try your suggestion but the pop up still does not appear

Comment: mmm I have update my test page and still don't work (in the fiddle page works well but I have not the javascript script in the head section (as usual) but in the body section). Here you can see that don't work: http://www.onofri.org/example/example4/

Answer (score 0):

You are using a <a> tag, change it to use a <div> tag, or remove <a> tag at all

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript) to make div clickable.

Comment: mmm don't work...if I remove the <a> tag the english flag is show but it is not clickable

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript)