# Images not showing as a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I suspect I'm doing something stupid but I have some hyperlinks styled as images with css but they don't work as links.

Experimental page is at http://cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/jm3/index.php/what-s-on
and it's the 'Read more' and 'buy tickets' buttons.
The page is built by php but the html looks like this...

```
<td>
<div class="sg-read-more">
<a href="#">Find out more</a>
</div>
<div class="sg-book-ticket">
<a href="http://www.ticketsource.co.uk/event/70577" target="_blank">Book Ticket</a>
</div>
</td>
```

The CSS is this....

```
div.sg-book-ticket {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;  
        background:url(images/buy-ticket.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
        right:15px;
        bottom:2px; 
        width:80px;
        height:40px;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        }

div.sg-book-ticket:hover {
background-position:0 -40px;
        }
```

The images display correctly and the rollover works, but they aren't links.
What have I missed?

Comment: *..I have some hyperlinks styled as images with css ...*: No. You have `div`s with background images.

Comment: either style the links and take out the `<div>` or use `jquery` to target the links for example. You are only making the text clickable not the whole div.

Comment: Thanks all. As you say, moving the style to the link worked.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would style the link as opposed to the div

```
div.sg-book-ticket{
 position:absolute;  
 right:15px;
 bottom:2px; 
}  
div.sg-book-ticket > a{
    display:block;       
    background:url(images/buy-ticket.png) no-repeat 0 0;       
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

div.sg-book-ticket a:hover{
    background-position:0 -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the whole div to be clickable, use this :

```
<td>
<a href="#">
<span class="sg-read-more">
</span>
</a>
<a href="http://www.ticketsource.co.uk/event/70577" target="_blank">
<span class="sg-book-ticket">
</span>
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: It will work yes, but It will show up as invalid when testing the compatibility. Unless you are using HTML5, it is invalid to nest a block element inside an inline element.

Comment: @chriz it is **not** bad practice to wrap a div in a `<a>`

Comment: @web-tiki I'm sorry, but, it is. Look everywhere. [or here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript)

Comment: it's better to use `span` instead of `div` inside of the `a` element

Comment: @chriz Sorry...I think you're a little out of date - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: @chriz http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/ + if you had read the link you posted you would have seen it is now possible to wrap a div in a link.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?:

```
<a href="<a href="http://www.ticketsource.co.uk/event/70577" target="_blank" alt="book ticket" />
<img src="images/buy-ticket.png" />
</a>
```

instead of putting the image in the css?