# Make <a> follows <li> parent width

Tags: html, css

I have some `<a>` wrapped in a `<li>`,
I want to make width of each `<a>` follows width of `<li>` which is same for each `<li>` so all the area of every `<li>` (area of `<a>` too) is clickable.

I set `width : 100%` in `<a>` then set specific width for `<li>` but didn't work. How can it be done?

Please Help. Thank you very much

This is my code :

HTML :

```
<ul class='sidenav'>
<?php   
  foreach ($menu as $key => $value) 
  {
  echo "<li> <a href=".$value[2].".php>".$value[1]."</a> </li>";
  }
?>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
#sidenav li{
  border     : 1px solid red;
  padding    : 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  margin-top : 10px;
  width      : 250px;
}

#sidenav li a{
  border  : 1px solid green;
  padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width   : 100%;
}
```

[image: this is the result]

Comment: can you post the HTML or the fiddle please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `display:block` property in `li a`

Here is your code in action https://jsfiddle.net/sw556vrv/3/

```
#sidenav li{
  border     : 1px solid red;
  margin-top : 10px;
  width      : 250px;
  height     : 100px;
}

#sidenav li a{
  border  : 1px solid green;
  margin: 0px auto;  
  display:block; // <-- read about this property
  width   : 100%; // <-- 100% or parent
  height : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! I read about block property, it says that "A block-level element starts on a new line and stretches out to the left and right as far as it can." So that's why the reason when I set `<a>` property to block, the <a> stretches out to fit its <li> parent. Great, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`a` tag is by default `inline` element.setting width of `inline` element wont work.so change your `a`'s `display` style property to `inline-block` or `block.`

```
#sidenav li a{
   border  : 1px solid green;
   padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   width   : 100%;
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, bro! Yes, I've just read about display properties. Block display will stretch out to left and right as far as it can, so in my case the block-setting <a> will strech to fit its <li> parent. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Look at [How to make a whole 'div' clickable in html and css without javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript)

That is essentially the same issue solved with a div.

Comment: Yes, thanks man! It can be solved just by setting <a> to have block display property. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in you have `<ul class="sidenav">` but in css you have written sidenav as identificator (id).

So, change

```
#sidenav li{
  border     : 1px solid red;
  padding    : 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  margin-top : 10px;
  width      : 250px;
}

#sidenav li a{
  border  : 1px solid green;
  padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width   : 100%;
}
```

on

```
.sidenav li{
  border     : 1px solid red;
  padding    : 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  margin-top : 10px;
  width      : 250px;
}

.sidenav li a{
  border  : 1px solid green;
  padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width   : 100%;
}
```

or `<ul class="sidenav">` to `<ul id="sidenav">`.

And then you may make changes recommended in other answers, if anchor tag will not take all width of parent tag (`li`) ... mostly change of display on `block`, as user Urahara says.