# Larger Clickable block ie <div> tags point to a link while contain multiple links inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to create a larger clickable link area ie div point to a link while contain multiple link inside with regular `<a>` tag that links to another direction than container ie `<div>` tag above?

I want to create such index page where each one of article behaves like a large clickable area that contain many links like image point to gallery or maybe another related topic. That big container just go to regular detail article. at the end my reader have big area if wanna go to detail while contain many additional link inside that container.

Is that possible to achieve that case using only css or maybe jquery combine with css? I need your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

No, very easy to work around this using several methods:

1. You can set a link around the div code, which is perfectly acceptable:

   ```
   <a href="http://example.com">
       <div>anything</div>
   </a>
   ```

   Then fill your div or set a background image of the article if needed.
2. Use a span or second div tag to fill up the entire divider, with the article as a background image. This method will not allow you to regularly populate the div through dynamic content:

   CSS:

   ```
   #my-div {
       background-color: #f00;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
   }
   a.fill-div {
       display: block;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
   ```

   HTML:

   ```
   <div id="my-div">
       <a href="#" class="fill-div"></a>
   </div>
   ```

Detailed in depth here: [How to make a whole 'div' clickable in html and css without javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript)

Comment: to display code inside list items indent each line of code with extra 4 spaces, upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with just CSS.

**Demo http://jsbin.com/dororo/edit?html,css,output**

**HTML**

```
<div class="Card">
  <a class="Card-title" href="#primary-link">This is a clickable link</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#another-link">another link</a> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

  <!-- Link overlay element -->
  <a class="Card-link" href="#primary-link" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a>
</div><!-- end Card -->
```

Note: I added `aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"` to prevent screen readers and keyboard users from interacting with this link since it would be redundant.

**Sass**

```
.Card {
  position: relative;

  // Link overlay
  &-link {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  // Allow other link to be hoverable through the link overlay
  a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

I believe I first saw this particular technique on the [Guardian’s homepage](http://www.theguardian.com/us).