# Button with Div on html 5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want make a div clickable - so that it will show a panel to select the language of the website. I don't want a `<select>`, I want do it with a div.

I tried searching it on the internet but I don't now exactly how to find it.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried, did you try putting a click event on your div?

Comment: There should be a plenty of other sites where you can do a keyword search for how to make a DOM element into a button. If you have trouble making some particular DIV clickable, then you should show what that div is (and what you've already done).

Comment: @bhansa I don´t know how do it, can send me a link to learn? I don´t want the code, I want learn how do it

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript

Comment: @bhansa Thanks :D

Comment: Avoid making any element except those like `<a>`, `<input>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>`, etc clickable unless you want to add all of the features, attributes, and event handlers needed to get those elements to work properly in a screen reader for the blind. Use the proper tag for the proper action. `<a>` is for page-to-page navigation and `<button>` or `<input type="button">` is for on-page actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery animations to perform what you want to perform as click events can trigger movement. Research a little bit on that and you should be able to get what you want. You can also do it with a form input list selector (that could actually be a much better otion).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the click on your DIV, giving it an id: `<div id="yourDivId">`

```
$('#yourDivId').on('click', function(){
    (...) \\ do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HTML attribute onclick** like

```
 <div onclick="href='www.mysite.com'">Click me</div>
```

Example below

```css
#myDiv{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" onclick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com';">Click me</div>
```