# structure problem between acf fields and shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I'm encountering an error in this code.
I suspect interference between the first ***a*** tag (lien_parrainage) and the second ***a*** tag (lien_avis).
In fact, the html return is as follows:

- if there is no link_notice, the structure is fine
- if a link_advice is present, several  tags with link_advice are created

I've turned the code every which way and I can't find it.

If I can simplify my code, I'd be delighted to have your recommendation.

```
function parrainage_shortcode($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'parrainage');

    $post_id = $atts['id'];

    $output = '';

    if (!empty($post_id)) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);

        if ($post) {
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array(80, 80)); 
            $title = get_the_title($post_id);
            $description = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
            $lien_parrainage = get_field('lien_parrainage', $post_id);
            $lien_avis = get_field('lien_avis', $post_id);
            $offre_prefixe = get_field('offre_prefixe', $post_id); 
            $offre = get_field('offre', $post_id);
            $offre_suffixe = get_field('offre_suffixe', $post_id);
            $note = get_field('note', $post_id);
            $mettre_en_avant_value = get_field('mettre_en_avant', $post_id);

            if (!empty($lien_parrainage)) {
            $output .= '<a href="' . $lien_parrainage . '">';
            }
            $output .= '<div class="parrainage_1 ' . $mettre_en_avant_value . '">';
            $output .= '<div class="parrainage-image-title-note">';
            $output .= '<div class="parrainage-image">' . $image . '</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="parrainage-title">';
            $output .= '<span class="parrainage-title-link">' . $title . '</span>';

if (!empty($note)) {
    $output .= '<span class="parrainage-note">'; 
    $output .= '<span class="parrainage-note-value">' . $note . '</span>'; 
    $output .= '</span>';
}
            if (get_post_type() !== 'avis' && !empty($lien_avis)) {
                $output .= '<a class="parrainage-lien-avis" href="' . $lien_avis . '">Notre avis</a>'; 
            }

            $output .= '</div>'; // div parrainage-title
            $output .= '</div>'; // div parrainage-image-title-note

            if (!empty($description)) {
                $output .= '<div class="parrainage-description">' . $description . '</div>';
            }
            
            $output .= '<div class="parrainage-offres">';
            $output .= '<div class="parrainage-offre-labels">';

            if (!empty($offre_prefixe)) {
                $output .= '<p class="parrainage-offre-prefixe">' . $offre_prefixe . '</p>';
            }
            if (!empty($offre)) {
                $output .= '<span class="parrainage-offre-offre">' . $offre . '</span>';
            }
            if (!empty($offre_suffixe)) {
                $output .= '<p class="parrainage-offre-suffixe">' . $offre_suffixe . '</p>'; 
            }
           
            $output .= '</div>'; // div parrainage-offre-labels
            
            if (!empty($lien_parrainage)) { 
            $output .= '<span class="parrainage-lien-parrainage button">Découvrir l\'offre</span>'; 
            }
            
            $output .= '</div>'; // div parrainage-offres
            $output .= '</div>'; // div parrainage_1
            $output .= '</a>'; 
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('parrainage', 'parrainage_shortcode');
```

Comment: You need to be specific about what is not working with examples.  You also mentioned link_advice which is not in your code whatsoever.  I assume this is in regards to wordpress.  Make sure you tag your question correctly so people have some context.

Comment: Note that in your HTML, you should not embed a **lien_avis** link inside **lien_parrainage** link…

Comment: Thanks for your lead, you've helped me understand what's not working. I've revised my code so that my first <a> tag closes immediately and I'm managing the link by making it take up 100% of the size of the div.

This topic helped me after your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript